# Run console application on host server

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, console-application

I've created a c# console app that uses the class `HttpListener` on some random port. The app listens to http post requests and performs some operations on mySQL database according to the details of the request.

At this point I wish to upload this application and the DB to a host server. What would be the best practice for it?

1. should I convert the .exe to .aspx that processes http requests on
   port 80? (my intuition told me that a console app would run faster
   than an .aspx page, but it might be wrong)
2. should I convert it to
   windows service? Is it possible? Is there a point to it? If I do,
   can I run it on a web hosting server?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best pratice would be a windows services, it is allways running when the server is up. A web project is would only run when you have request to a page in the project, because you have your own webserver this would be a little stange.